# Installing Koala (Development Kit) in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I've recently switched to Ubuntu. I've also moved most of my development area to Ubuntu as well. The only thing that I'm missing is a compresser and minifier for my LESS and Javascript files. On Mac I've used CodeKit and Prespos on Windows, but now I need an option for Ubuntu. What would be the best alternative?

I've found out about [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) which seems pretty decent, but I have no idea how to install it. It downloads a `tar.gz` archive, but I don't know what to do with it, except extract it.

If you have a better similar tool to suggest, please let me know. Otherwise please give me a guide on how to install Koala on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you're trying to install the tar.gz version? You can download the .deb packages here [for 64 bit](http://www.amazon.com/gp/drive/share?ie=UTF8&s=2JRLmMZ_S5Iq8fzAZifUY0) or [for 32 bit](http://www.amazon.com/gp/drive/share?ie=UTF8&s=0IyKOEzMRXkr9gFyXCKVZk). Then, just double click the one you need and software-center or gdebi should install it.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could simply double click on that file and start installing it. I kept right clicking and then selecting _Extract_. Thanks.